# How to handle a failed login with ZfcUser's LoginWidget?

Tags: redirect, authentication, widget, zend-route, zfcuser

In my Zend Framework 2 application I am using the [zfcUserLoginWidget](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/View/Helper/ZfcUserLoginWidget.php), a View Helper provided by [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki). This View Helper is meant to *embed* the login form on another page.

```
<?php echo $this->zfcUserLoginWidget(); ?>
```

I use this View Helper in my *index.phtml* which is controlled by my *IndexController*. Pressing the "Login" button calls the *loginAction* function of the *UserController*. If the entered login data are invalid, the *UserController* redirects by default to the login page:

```
class UserController extends AbstractActionController
{
    const ROUTE_LOGIN = 'zfcuser/login';    // Leads to 'user/login'

    public function loginAction()
    {
        // ...

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('zfcuser-login-form')->addMessage($this->failedLoginMessage);
            return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->url()->fromRoute(static::ROUTE_LOGIN).($redirect ? '?redirect='. rawurlencode($redirect) : ''));
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

The *login.phtml* displays by default an error message if the entered login data has been invalid:

```
<?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('identity')) ?>
```

In my application I have **changed** the redirection route back to the *index.phtml* (to the LoginWidget) controlled by the *IndexController* instead of the *login.phtml* controlled by the *UserController*:

```
const ROUTE_LOGIN = 'home';    // Leads to 'index/index'
```

Changing this redirection route causes the loss of error messages: The previously mentioned *formElementErrors* function is still called, but there are no messages available anymore.

### Question:

- How can I inform the LoginWidget about the fact that there has been entered invalid login data and that the page has not only been simply reloaded?

I'd like to colorize the input fields red if that is the case...

Answer (score 0):

having the same problem i solved it using use Zend\Session\Container, generating my own message.

Modified:
ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Controller\UserController.php

Add

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

const ROUTE_LOGIN        = 'home';
```

in loginAction of UserController.php added/changed

```
//open session
$session = new Container('loginmsg');

if (!$form->isValid()) {
//$this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('zfcuser-login-form')->addMessage($this->failedLoginMessage);
//$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('not working');
//return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->url()->fromRoute(static::ROUTE_LOGIN).($redirect ? '?redirect='.$redirect : ''));
$session->loginmsg = 'Username and password do not match.'; //store loginmsg
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
} else {
$session->loginmsg = "";
}
```

Also modify the authenticateAction

```
if (!$auth->isValid()) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('zfcuser-login-form')->addMessage($this->failedLoginMessage);
            $adapter->resetAdapters();
            //open session
            $session = new Container('loginmsg');
            $session->loginmsg = 'Username and password do not match.'; //store loginmsg
            return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->url()->fromRoute(static::ROUTE_LOGIN)
                . ($redirect ? '?redirect='.$redirect : ''));
        }
```

In the home Route (indexAction):

```
    $session = new Container('loginmsg');

    $loginmsg = strip_tags($session->loginmsg);

    $session->getManager()->getStorage()->clear('loginmsg');

    $this->layout('layout/index');

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'loginmsg' => $loginmsg,
    ));
```

In the View of the Index

```
<?php if(!(empty($loginmsg))):?>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><?php echo $loginmsg;?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Worked for me (at first), msg me for further information.

Kind regards,
David